# Tint color of controls darker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, tintcolor

When I set the `tintcolor` for a `UISegmentedControl`, the color it show up as on the iPhone is darker than the actual color I selected. It is the exact color in `IB`, and the simulator, just darker on the iPhone. For instance, if I set the `BG color` of a view to `UIColor` `greenColor`, and the tint of a control to `greenColor`, they will both look the same as each other on the computer, but not on an iPhone. Any idea how to make the control the exact color I'm trying to set?

[image]

Comment: can u show the screenshot of the issue ?

Comment: Added to the original post. You will see I have the tint color set to green on a button and on the background color of a view. On the simulator they are the same color. On the iPhone, the button tint color shows up darker.

Comment: Does your mac has retina display ? Iphone has the retina display resolution. So there should be some slight differene in the display.

Comment: Yes, I have retina display on my Mac. I understand that a color may appear differently on two different devices, but both controls should appear different, not just one.